# how to get Snippets of text via Hibernate Search Engine with Lucene with Highlighter and StandardAnalyzer

Tags: java, hibernate, lucene, hibernate-search

I was reading about Hibernate search engine with Lucene and I was able to set it up as follow on an Article class that holds an article via mysql db. my goal is to display to the user the tittle of the Article and snippet of the text that they are searching on the browser. This is what I have implemented so far:

```
@Entity
@Indexed
@Analyzer(impl = StandardAnalyzer.class)
@Table(name = "ARTICLE", catalog = "kefet3")
public class Article implements java.io.Serializable {


private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
// Fields

private Integer id;
private Articlelanguage articlelanguage;
private Users users;
private Articlecategory articlecategory;
@Analyzer(impl = StandardAnalyzer.class)
@Field(index = Index.YES, analyze = Analyze.YES, store = Store.NO)
private String artTitle;
@Field(index = Index.YES, analyze = Analyze.YES, store = Store.NO)
private String artContent;
```

for the above code there are get and set and all the annotation for the db.

below is the method that searches.

```
   @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<Article> search(String word) {

        analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_36);
        FullTextSession fullTextSession = Search.getFullTextSession(getCurrentSession());


        // get a query builder
        QueryBuilder queryBuilder = fullTextSession.getSearchFactory()
                .buildQueryBuilder().forEntity(Article.class).get();

        // build the query
        org.apache.lucene.search.Query query = queryBuilder.keyword().
                onFields("artTitle","artContent")
                .matching(word).createQuery();


       FullTextQuery fullTextQuery = fullTextSession.createFullTextQuery(query, Article.class);


        // wrap Lucene query in a javax.persistence.Query
       // org.hibernate.Query fullTextQuery = fullTextSession.createFullTextQuery(query, Article.class);

        List<Article> searchResultList =  fullTextQuery.list();

        for (int i=0; i<searchResultList.size(); i++){
            System.out.println("searchResultList###################"+searchResultList.get(i).getArtTitle());
        }




        Highlighter highlighter = new Highlighter( new QueryScorer( query ) );

        highlighter.setTextFragmenter( new SimpleFragmenter( 20 ) );

        int maxNumFragmentsRequired = 3;

        for(Article art: searchResultList){
            String artContent = art.getArtContent();
            String artTitle = art.getArtTitle();

            TokenStream tokenStream1 =
                    analyzer.tokenStream( "artContent", new StringReader( artContent ) );
            TokenStream tokenStream2 =
                    analyzer.tokenStream( "artTitle", new StringReader( artTitle ) );


            String result=null;
            String resul2=null;
            try {
                result = highlighter.getBestFragments( tokenStream1, artContent, maxNumFragmentsRequired, " ..." );

                resul2 = highlighter.getBestFragments( tokenStream2, artTitle, maxNumFragmentsRequired, " ..." );

            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                System.out.println("((((((((((((((((((((IOException))))))))))))))))))))"+e);
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InvalidTokenOffsetsException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                System.out.println("((((((((((((((((((((InvalidTokenOffsetsException))))))))))))))))))))"+e);
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            System.out.println( result );

            System.out.println( resul2 );       
        }

    //    fullTextSession.close();

        return searchResultList;
    }
```

The result that I am getting is:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No match found
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:973)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
com.github.dandelion.datatables.core.web.filter.DatatablesFilter.doFilter(DatatablesFilter.java:73)

root cause

java.lang.IllegalStateException: No match found
java.util.regex.Matcher.group(Matcher.java:485)
java.util.regex.Matcher.group(Matcher.java:445)
com.kefet.dao.impl.SearchDAOImpl.search(SearchDAOImpl.java:125)
com.kefet.service.impl.SearchServiceImpl.search(SearchServiceImpl.java:47)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:262)
org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
com.sun.proxy.$Proxy48.search(Unknown Source)
com.kefet.controller.SearchController.searchText(SearchController.java:30)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:749)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:689)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:938)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
com.github.dandelion.datatables.core.web.filter.DatatablesFilter.doFilter(DatatablesFilter.java:73)
```

The tutorial that I have found was on this link below:

https://code.google.com/p/hibernatesearchinaction/source/browse/trunk/ch13/src/com/manning/hsia/dvdstore/TestHighlighter.java?r=86

my pom file contain this:

```
<hibernate.version>4.3.5.Final</hibernate.version>
<hibernate-search-orm.version>4.5.1.Final</hibernate-search-orm.version>
<hibernate-search-analyzers.version>4.5.1.Final</hibernate-search-analyzers.version>
<hibernate-search-infinispan.version>4.5.1.Final</hibernate-search-infinispan.version>
<lucene-highlighter.version>4.9.0</lucene-highlighter.version>
<lucene-analyzers-common.version>4.9.0</lucene-analyzers-common.version>

<mysql.connector.version>5.1.30</mysql.connector.version>

<dependency>
<groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
<artifactId>hibernate-search-orm</artifactId>
<version>${hibernate-search-orm.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
<artifactId>hibernate-search-analyzers</artifactId>
<version>${hibernate-search-analyzers.version}</version>
</dependency>


<dependency>
<groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
<artifactId>hibernate-search-infinispan</artifactId>
<version>${hibernate-search-infinispan.version}</version>
</dependency>   

<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
<artifactId>lucene-highlighter</artifactId>
<version>${lucene-highlighter.version}</version>
</dependency>   

<dependency>
<groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
<artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
<version>${hibernate.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
<artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
<version>${hibernate.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do it using token streams, but here is a result of some hacking job on hibernate search from last 3 hrs. It really needs hacking to perform simple tasks. This solution finally works with HS 4.5.1 and Lucene 3.6.2 (IBaseEntity is "something" with id):

```
public static final String HIGHLIGHTER_PRE = "<span class='search-found'>";
public static final String HIGHLIGHTER_POST = "</span>";

protected static DocumentBuilderIndexedEntity getDocumentBuilder(Session session, Class clazz) {
    FullTextSession fullTextSession = Search.getFullTextSession(session);
    SearchFactoryImplementor searchFactoryImplementor =
        (SearchFactoryImplementor) fullTextSession.getSearchFactory();
    EntityIndexBinding entityIndexBinding = searchFactoryImplementor.getIndexBinding(clazz);
    return entityIndexBinding.getDocumentBuilder();
}

/**
 * Provides lucene document for given entity.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static Document getDocument(Session session, IBaseEntity o, Class clazz) {
    return getDocumentBuilder(session, clazz).getDocument(o, o.getId(), new HashMap<String, String>(),
        new HibernateSessionLoadingInitializer((SessionImplementor) session),
        new ContextualExceptionBridgeHelper());
}

/**
 * Provides lucene analyzer for given entity.
 */
public static Analyzer getAnalyzer(Session session, Class clazz) {
    return getDocumentBuilder(session, clazz).getAnalyzer();
}

/**
 * @param luceneQuery You have it before you create {@link FullTextQuery} from {@link FullTextSession}.
 */
public static Highlighter getHighlighter(Query luceneQuery) {
    Highlighter highlighter = new Highlighter(new SimpleHTMLFormatter(HIGHLIGHTER_PRE, HIGHLIGHTER_POST),
        new QueryScorer(luceneQuery));
    highlighter.setTextFragmenter(new SimpleFragmenter());
    return highlighter;
}

/**
 * Returns entity raw lucene text content without any analyzer usage (ie. even with HTML tags).
 */
public static String getFullTextContent(Session session, IBaseEntity o) {
    if (o==null)
        return "";

    Set<String> strings = new LinkedHashSet<String>(); // to avoid multiple same strings
    Document document = getDocument(session, o, o.getClass());

    List<org.apache.lucene.document.Field> fields = new ArrayList<org.apache.lucene.document.Field>();

    // here is the part where we should add fields by name to text content (manually as well)
    for (String fieldName : listIndexedFields(o.getClass()))
        fields.addAll(Arrays.asList(document.getField(fieldName)));

    for (org.apache.lucene.document.Field field: fields) {
        if (field!=null) {
            String s = field.stringValue();
            if (!StringUtils.isBlank(s))
                strings.add(s);
        }
    }

    if (strings.isEmpty())
        return "";

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (String s: strings) {
        if (sb.length()>0)
            sb.append(" ");
        sb.append(s);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}

/**
 * @return Lucene highlighter text for search results for given object.
 */
public static String getHighlighterText(Session session, IBaseEntity o, Query query) {
    Analyzer analyzer = getAnalyzer(session, o.getClass());
    Highlighter highlighter = getHighlighter(query);
    return getHighlightedText(analyzer, highlighter, getFullTextContent(session, o));
}

public static String getHighlightedText(Analyzer analyzer, Highlighter highlighter, String fullTextContent) {
    try {
        return highlighter.getBestFragment(analyzer, null, fullTextContent);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Cannot highlight lucene results", e);
    }
}
```